# SQL Server Real and Float datatype cast conversions do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are undergoing a migration in our tool. Some of the datatypes in our tables have been changed from real to float. To understand the impact I have run the following code:

```
declare @realVariable as real,
@floatVariable as float

set @realVariable=152304.11999512
set @floatVariable=152304.11999512

select cast(@realVariable AS decimal(15, 4)) as realcol,str(@floatVariable,15,4) as floatcol
```

The result is different for both real and float variables:
real=152304.1250
float=    152304.1200

How can I make sure that the float result is same as real?

Comment: `SELECT  CAST(CAST(CAST(152304.11999512 AS REAL) AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(15,4))`?

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you want a less accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

float and real are both approximate-number data types for floating point numeric data.

real is the same as float(24). If you declare float without a suffix, then it means float(53).

So, you are converting from real (which is float(24)) to float(53). You are simply making the numbers more precise.

float(24) has a precision of 7 digits and float(53) has a precision of 15 digits.

See Books Online > float and real (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173773.aspx

If we repeat your example and display the variables without conversion, we can see that the real variable is displayed with 7 digits precision, and float variable is displayed with 14 digits precision, which is exactly what you set it to.

```
DECLARE @realVariable as real,
@floatVariable as float;

-- Set to a number with 14 digits precision
SET @realVariable=152304.11999512;
SET @floatVariable=152304.11999512;

SELECT @realVariable AS '@realVariable', @floatVariable AS '@floatVariable';
```

[image]

The simple answer to your question is that the two numbers are not the same. The one with float(53) is more precise.

Calculating the ABS of the difference of the two numbers and then comparing this to an acceptable threshold is one way to do it. However this would not be satisfactory if the scale can vary widely.

To illustrate why this might not be satisfactory:

```
r = 0.0001234567
f = 0.00012345678901234
```

Comparing the difference to a threshold of 0.0005 would not be useful.

So it might be better to use a threshold that is a percentage of the number.

```
DECLARE @threshold AS float, @delta AS float;
SET @threshold = ABS(@floatVariable / 1000000);
SET @delta = ABS(@floatVariable - CAST(@realVariable AS float));

SELECT @realVariable AS '@realVariable',
    @floatVariable AS '@floatVariable',
    @threshold AS '@threshold',
    @delta AS '@delta',
    CASE
        WHEN @delta < @threshold THEN N'OK'
        ELSE N'Different'
    END AS 'Comparison';
```

[image]

Note: This solution might need a bit of adjustment for numbers that are very close to zero.

Comment: "However this would not be satisfactory if the scale can vary widely." -- sure it would. Scale and precision are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

@RichardCL's description describes the way things work (+1). Now, if you are converting a value stored as a `real` datatype value into a value stored as a `float` datatype value, then the entire and precise "original" value will be stored in the resulting value--you will lose no information from your existing set of `real` values.

Referring to your example, your value of 152304.11999512 cannot be stored precisely as a `real` value--it will be rounded and stored as 152304.125.  Convert this to a `float`, and you will still have 152304.125.

Comment: The impression I got from the question is that the numbers are going to be recalculated, but that might not be so.

Comment: I interpreted it as "we changed our columns from Real to Float, are the stored numbers still ok"? So yes, the actual problem being addressed is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

You need a delta. Compute the absolute value of the difference between the real and float values then make sure that is less than your delta. The delta should be sufficiently small to meet your needs.

For example using your values:
abs(152304.1250 - 152304.1200) <= .0050 so the use .0050 as your delta value.

Comment: in our case 0.0050 makes a lot of difference hence we cannot afford a delta.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question. For your purposes you cannot reliably compare a real with a float.

Comment: @Somita, if precision is important to you , then you should NOT be using real or float but an exact numeric datatype. Both numbers are currently approximations.

Comment: @HLGEM You mean, like an integer?

Comment: Or Numeric where you specify the number of decimal places